# A field or property name was not found in the selected data source

Tags: c#, asp.net, oop

I have a List that reads from a stored procedure. Its only a select statement. I dont know why I get the error "A field or property name 'Ticket ID' was not found in the selected data source." What Im doing is populating the gridview with my code with pre-defined columns.

```
  public List<SelectQueuedTickets> GetQueuedTickets()
    {
        List<SelectQueuedTickets> QueuedTicketsList = new List<SelectQueuedTickets>();

        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString))
        {

            using (SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("[Reader].[usp_SelectQueuedTickets]", con))
            {
                con.Open();
                com.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                SqlDataReader rd = com.ExecuteReader();

               while (rd.Read())
                {
                    this.TicketID = Convert.ToString(rd["Ticket ID"]);
                    this.PriorityID = Convert.ToInt32(rd["Priority"]);
                    this.FormType = Convert.ToString(rd["Form Type"]);
                    this.Summary = Convert.ToString(rd["Summary"]);
                    this.CreationDate = Convert.ToDateTime(rd["Creation Date"]);
                    this.OwnerGroup = Convert.ToString(rd["Owner Group"]);
                    this.Owner = Convert.ToString(rd["Owner"]);
                    this.Creator = Convert.ToInt32(rd["Creator"]);
                    this.AffectedUser = Convert.ToInt32(rd["Affected User"]);
                    this.OwnerEmail = Convert.ToString(rd["Owner Email"]);
                    this.AffectedUserEmail = Convert.ToString(rd["Affected User Email"]);

                    QueuedTicketsList.Add(this);
                }
            }
        }
        return QueuedTicketsList;

    }


   protected void LoadQueuedTickets()
    {
        SelectQueuedTickets selectqueuedtickets = new SelectQueuedTickets();
        GridView1.DataSource = selectqueuedtickets.GetQueuedTickets();
        GridView1.DataBind();
    }
```

Comment: I am assuming your question is "Why am I getting this error and how can I fix it?". In that case, please indicate which line you are getting the error on, remove all other lines unnecessary to reproducing the problem, and most importantly include a pared-down version of your stored procedure that still produces the issue. If need be, you should also include some sample data, but I do not believe that will be necessary in this case.

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be a mismatch between what you're returning and expecting back from the stored procedure. 
I would compare field by field to see that there are no missing or misspelled column names. 
Run the proc in Management studio and compare it to the fields you are referencing in code

Comment: my columns in SQL is named "fld_Fname as First Name". is that a mismatch?

Comment: You only have to worry about columns you're referencing in code. Extra columns returned from the stored proc don't matter